# What is the syntax to insert the object itself in a jsRender template?

Tags: jquery, jsrender

If I have an array of objects, I can render one of its properties  using this syntax: `{{=propertyName}}`. But what is the syntax if I want to render the object itself?

```
<script id="template1" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div>Value {{the_object_itself}} </div>      <<==========What do I put here?
</script>

<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var data = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
        $("#output").html($("#template1").render(data));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the object is a value, or something you want to do toString() on, you can simply do `{{>#data}}` (updated comment with the current syntax) - which inserts the HTML-encoded value. Or you can write `{{:#data}}` if you don't want HTML encoding.